# Is it possible to stop the alarm manager based on number of times

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

Please help..Thanks in advance.

App is working fine but my need to stop the alarm after no of time  (in integer) - added by me in order to stop the alarm after 9 days.[Getting Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFtZH.jpg)
public void setRepeatAlarm(Context context, Calendar calendar, int ID, long RepeatTime) {
mAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

```
    // Put Reminder ID in Intent Extra
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ReminderEditActivity.EXTRA_REMINDER_ID, Integer.toString(ID));

    mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    // Calculate notification timein
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    long currentTime = c.getTimeInMillis();
    long diffTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis() - currentTime;

    // Start alarm using initial notification time and repeat interval time

        mAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + diffTime,
                RepeatTime, mPendingIntent);

    // Restart alarm if device is rebooted
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(context, BootReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver,
            PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

How to stop the repeating alarm based on no of times.(Eg: start date is 12-11-2020 and end date is 15-12-2020 - i m giving input as no of times(3 times) not as end date.)
How to do that. Please help

Thanks..

Comment: It's very difficult to try and help you without seeing an example of the code that you've written.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @RiaanNel, Added code and screenshot. please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can locally store the number of times Alarm has triggered and number of time Alarm needs to trigger in something like `SharedPreferences` and before each execution check if the number is higher or not.

Another solution would be to calculate the date in `x` days, then save that date in `SharedPreferences` and before each execution check if today is the date that we saved, if yes - cancel that Alarm.

```
class MySharedPreferences(context: Context) {
    private val preferences: SharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    private val preferencesEditor: SharedPreferences.Editor = preferences.edit()

    fun setDeadlineOfAlarm(days: Int) {
        preferencesEditor.putInt(PREF_KEY_DEADLINE, days)
        preferencesEditor.apply()
    }

    fun setCurrentDaysTriggered(days: Int) {
        preferencesEditor.putInt(PREF_KEY_CURRENT_DAYS, days)
        preferencesEditor.apply()
    }

    fun getDeadlineOfAlarm(): Int = preferences.getInt(PREF_KEY_DEADLINE, 0)
    fun getCurrentDaysTriggered(): Int = preferences.getInt(PREF_KEY_CURRENT_DAYS, 0)


    companion object {
        private const val PREF_FILE_NAME = "AlarmPreferences"
        private const val PREF_KEY_DEADLINE = "Alarm_Deadline"
        private const val PREF_KEY_CURRENT_DAYS = "Alarm_Current_Days"
    }
}
```

Comment: Vitaliy,thanks for reply. Could you please share code for your first solution. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Added information on how you can save. From there, you should have a basic idea on how to work with things and should be able to figure out how to do what you need.

Comment: Vitaliy, I will save the notification when user click on save. I need to add this shared preferences inside the save reminder method.  If so, how shared preferences internally stop the alarm based on amountofdays =3. How it link? Please explain

Comment: @MagnusInfanteena I am not going to write fully working code for you. If you have the working sample of Alarm Manager, you should be able to go from here and figure this out

Comment: I am not asking fully working code. But, to know where to place your shared preferences and how it will work. Thanks for the help. I m new to Android app development. Developing prayer app. With my own interest, doing this.

Comment: @MagnusInfanteena I edited my post with a whole custom class where you define your usage of `Shared Preferences`. In your project, simply create new file, then anywhere you need and where you have Context, simply call this class and access the functions. You can put it anywhere in the project. Of course there are guidelines about proper app architecture, but that is a whole different topic to discuss